# OutOfMemory android error with CircleImageView and setBackgroundResource

Tags: android, firebase, out-of-memory, android-image

I have an activity in which I use 2 resources:

1 round image, like this:

```
String image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
Picasso.with(pilotProfileImage.getContext()).load(image)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.pilot_default).into(pilotProfileImage);
```

When thumb_image is a picture stored in Firebase Storage.

Another resource:

```
mImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.m_air);
```

While `R.drawable.m_air` is a drawable saved in my drawable folder

I'm receiving

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 10530520 free bytes and 10MB until OOM

I've seen solution with `Bitmap` but I'm not using bitmap here.

I've tried

```
mDroneImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mavic_air, 100, 100))
```

In this solution: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

but the app still crashes. In addition it doesn't solve the firebase image problem.

How can I solve it?

Edit: 
Found answers for the firebase problem in the docs:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Comment: what is the image resolution?

Comment: The firebase' picture: 2400*2400 jpg , the drawable: 640*640 png

Comment: Ok I used:
                Picasso.with(pilotProfileImage.getContext()).load(image)
                     .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.pilot_default).into(pilotProfileImage);

Added the fit(), 
And also reduced the sizes of the placeholder - pilot_default to smaller then 500dx, and it fixed the problem.

Another thing could be done is reduce the size of the drawable pictures, but currently it works without it

Comment: This is a non related firebase storage problem. You were trying to fit a huge image in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading a 2400x2400 pixel image, you're loading about 16MB of data. The process you're currently using, loads all the data in memory in order to display it. Apparently the phone you're trying to run this code on doesn't have that amount of memory available.

There is a great piece of [Picasso documentation on dealing with `OutOfMemory` errors while loading an image](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library#outofmemoryerror-loading-errors). Some of these approaches resize the image to reduce memory usage, so those should be a way for you to reduce memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I understand it better now. 
I solved the problem with Picasso documentation :)